# Terraform data.google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint is null

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I would like to manage configuration for a service using terraform to a GKE cluster defined using external terraform script.

I created the configuration using [`kubernetes_secret`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/secret).

Something like below

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "service_secret" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-secret"
    namespace = "my-namespace"
  }  

  data = {
    username = "admin"
    password = "P4ssw0rd"
  }
}
```

And I also put this google client configuration to configure the kubernetes provider.

```
data "google_client_config" "current" {

}

data "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "my-container"
  location = "asia-southeast1"
  zone = "asia-southeast1-a"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${data.google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint}"
  token                  = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate)
}
```

when I apply the terraform it shows error message below

[image: error]

`data.google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint is null`

Do I miss some steps here?

Comment: If you just have the `google_container_cluster` data source and output the full thing what does that show?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR how do I do it? can you give me the sample code?

Comment: Did you find the root cause of your error ?

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same/similar issue when trying to initialize the kubernetes provider from a google_container_cluster data source. `terraform show` just displayed all null values for the data source attributes. The fix for me was to specify the project in the data source, e.g.,

```
data "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name     = "my-container"
  location = "asia-southeast1"
  zone     = "asia-southeast1-a"
  project  = "my-project"
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/container_cluster#project

> project - (Optional) The project in which the resource belongs. If it is not provided, the provider project is used.

In my case the google provider was pointing to a different project than the one containing the cluster I wanted to get info about.

In addition, you should be able to remove the `zone` attribute from that block. `location` should refer to the zone if it is a zonal cluster or the region if it is a regional cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I wanted to start the cluster from scrach. No varible was declared then.
I solved it with depends on parameter in google_container_cluster block.

```
data "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name = var.project_name

  depends_on = [
    google_container_node_pool.e2-small
  ]
}
```

In my case the provider is waiting on nodes to be deployed. Kubernete provider starts working after the nodes are provisioned and variables are declared.

Answer (score 0):

##### my problem

the `name` wasn't right so the data returned nothing

##### I tried

```
data "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name     = "gke_my-project-name_us-central1_my-cluster-name"
  location = "us-central1"
}
```

But the name is wrong and needs to be just `my-cluster-name`

And most importantly, the data directive didn't say that this cluster didn't exist *--sad_beeps--*

##### Solution (in my case): double check that the cluster exists

```
data "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name     = "my-cluster-name"
  location = "us-central1"
}
```

hope it will save time for someone else